# Simulate user-creation in Firebase functions CLI

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm writing a function that is triggered whenever a new user is created in Firebase. Debugging this function takes me ages because I deploy the cloud function for every single change.
I use Firebase CLI to simulate other events in the database, but I can't figure out how to simulate a user creation correctly (with all the params).

To start the CLI I run:

```
firebase experimental:functions:shell
```

My function is:

```
exports.createTreeForNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data;
    console.log(user.uid);
    console.log(user.displayName);
    console.log(user.email);
    console.log(user.photoURL);
    console.log(user.metadata.creationTime);
    return null;
});
```

When I run the following command in the Firebase CLI:

```
createTreeForNewUser()
```

it prints `undefined` 4 times, followed by an exception because it can't extract `creationTime` from `undefined`.
This behavior makes sense, but no matter what I tried, I couldn't figure out how to pass the `event` correctly (so that the function will be able to extract all the params I need).

The question is:
How do I run the `createTreeForNewUser` with the `event` param set correctly?

Thanks!
Slavik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the user object to the function:

```
createTreeForNewUser({
    uid: 'xxx',
    displayName: 'John',
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    photoURL: 'https://...',
    metadata: {creationTime: 123}
})
```

Comment: Worked like magic, thanks! Just remove the extra '}' at the end of the 'metadata' line :)